# VSS error in eclipse-Failed to create ole client

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-sourcesafe

i want to share java source code through Virtual source safe (VSS) in eclipse.
while sharing i got an error
  [image]

how to fix this error..any answers will help me

Comment: have you check share permission and ntfs permission?